# How do i avoid dtd validation when reading response from a post in Java/Jboss

Tags: xml, validation, jboss, dtd, saxparser

Im running a JBoss 8.1 on windows 7, and trying to post a request to get a xml response and map it into my POJO's. I've done it with 1 url like this

```
WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(queryString);
Bean bean=webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(Bean.class);
```

and that gave me excactly what i wanted - a bunch of classes corresponding to the xml structure.

Now i wanted to do the same with a post and another url but im ending up with a FileNotFoundException and a reference to a dtd file in the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE oxip SYSTEM "combinations.dtd">
```

I dont want to do the validating so i did following :

```
javax.ws.rs.core.Response vResponse;
WebTarget target=ClientBuilder.newClient().target(queryString);
response = target.request(MediaType.TEXT_XML).post(Entity.text(apiRequest));
String string = vResponse.readEntity(String.class);


JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bean.class);
SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxParserFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);
XMLReader xmlReader = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(string));
SAXSource source = new SAXSource(xmlReader, inputSource);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
Bean bean = (Bean) unmarshaller.unmarshal(vSource);
```

Isnt there a way to aviod this explicit use of SaxParser and JaxBContext like configuring the jboss jaxb to not use validation ??

Comment: I really hope somebody is able to help on this one ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By inserting following code the problem was solved :

```
XMLReader vXmlReader = vSAXParserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();

//To avoid validating against external dtd which does not exist
EntityResolver entityResolver = new EntityResolver()  {
@Override
public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) throws SAXException, IOException {
    return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
  }
};

vXmlReader.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);

InputSource vInputSource = new InputSource(new StringReader(vMostPlayedResponse));
```